# Javascript to make Images link to a page

Tags: javascript

How do I make all the portfolio images on this page (http://makeupinsession.com), link to the porftolio page?   I tried doing it with JS but couldn't figure it out.

The images in question are in the black section where it says "My Beautiful Customers for Professional Makeup & Hair"

Thanks so much

Comment: You want all/any images to be a clickable link to open the portfolio page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all images to link to your portfolio, why not just make the entire container div a link?

```
<a href = "/portfolio">
    <div id = "jig1" //etc.....>
    </div>
</a>
```

This is valid HTML5.

Comment: Well, I actually did some digging with hotjar.com as I just launched the site and it seems like users were really eager to click images, so I turned the light box function on (it was originally off when I posted this question).